# Get last element from arryalist using drools DRL file

Tags: list, drools

I am trying the following code

```
rule "Last activity"
salience 1
when
  $notification : NotificationVO()
  lastActivityOffset:Integer()
  from  $notification.offsetChngesInterval.
  get($notification.offsetChngesInterval.size()-1)
then
  System.out.println("Hello--"+$notification.offsetChngesInterval.size());
end
```

It gives error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
Can anyone let me know what is causing this problem on the line

```
$notification.offsetChngesInterval.
get($notification.offsetChngesInterval.size()-1)
```

It does not allow me to get the last element from the list

Comment: Does NotificationVO have a  field `List<Integer> offsetChngesInterval`? Is there a public getOffsetChngesInteval?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the extraction of the Integer on the *left hand side*? You can do that easily on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is advisable to write

```
$notification : NotificationVO( offsetChngesIntervall != null && offsetChngesInterval.size() > 0 )
```

to make sure that the list isn't empty. Perhaps also a check that it is not null.

Comment: This solution worked. I am new to rule engine and did a silly mistake.Thanks